# CSS Media Queries always using the wrong one

Tags: css, media-queries

I have 2 media query one is for max-width:767 px the other one is (min-width: 412px) and (max-width: 767px) and css always using the first one I couldn't understand why. Sorry for my english btw ^^.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

            .responsive #svg_logo{display: block !important; width: 244px !important; padding-top: 12px !important; margin-left: -21px !important;}
            .responsive .logo img{visibility: hidden !important;}
            .responsive .logo {visibility: hidden !important;}
            .responsive #top #s {width: 80vw !important; position: relative !important; padding: 11px 47px 11px 5px !important; z-index: 1;margin-left: 40px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchform>div {position: relative !important;max-width: 542px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchsubmit {height: 41px;margin-right: 6px !important;margin-top: 2px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchsubmit, .ajax_load {width: 40px !important;height: 100% !important;line-height: 40px !important;padding: 0 !important;position: absolute !important;right: 0 !important;top: -1px !important;z-index$                .responsive #menu-item-shop .cart_dropdown_link {left: 79px !important;margin-top: -14px !important;}
            .responsive .av-hamburger-inner {width: 100% !important;right: 528px !important; margin-top: 57px !important;}
            .responsive #top .av_minimal_header #s {border: 2px solid !important;}
            .responsive .sub_menu{display: none;}
            .responsive #top #header_meta{display: none;}
            .responsive.html_mobile_menu_tablet #top #wrap_all .av-logo-container{height: 53px !important; width: 326px !important;}



    @media only screen and (min-width: 412px) and (max-width: 767px){
            .responsive #svg_logo{display: block !important; width: 244px !important; padding-top: 12px !important; margin-left: -31px !important;}
            .responsive .logo img{visibility: hidden !important;}
            .responsive .logo {visibility: hidden !important;}
            .responsive #top #s {width: 80vw !important; position: relative !important; padding: 11px 47px 11px 5px !important; z-index: 1;margin-left: 40px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchform>div {position: relative !important;max-width: 542px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchsubmit {height: 41px;margin-right: -11px !important;margin-top: 2px !important;}
            .responsive #top #searchsubmit, .ajax_load {width: 40px !important;height: 100% !important;line-height: 40px !important;padding: 0 !important;position: absolute !important;right: 21px !important;top: -1px !important;z-in$                .responsive #top .av_minimal_header #s {border: 2px solid !important;}
            .responsive .sub_menu{display: none;}
            .responsive .av-hamburger-inner {width: 100% !important;right: 459px !important; margin-top: 57px !important;}
            .responsive #top #header_meta{display: none;}
            .responsive.html_mobile_menu_tablet #top #wrap_all .av-logo-container{height: 53px !important; width: 326px !important;}
            .responsive #menu-item-shop .cart_dropdown_link{left: 80px !important; margin-top: -13px !important;}
```

sometimes some codes works and sometimes not.

Comment: Please include your code as text not an image.

Comment: ah okay sorry for that...

Comment: Now you still have shown us only _one_ of your media queries ... so we don't know whether the other one comes before or after that, whether there might be any syntax errors, etc. Please get into the habit of providing a proper [mre] when you ask questions like this.

Comment: I guess It's okay now

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what you say I can assume that you have to change your first media query to (min-width: 769px) (or even (min-width: 768px) not to leave any resolution unhandled)

Edit:
Because both media queries cover same max resolution with disitinction of that the first rule is not limited by min-height, your second set of rules does not apply, becuase rules that are defined first in CSS take precedence.

I'd change first media query to

`@media only screen and (max-width: 411px)`

Comment: I added my 767 px codes too

Comment: so can I add these media queries?

media only screen and (max-width: 411px)
media only screen and (max-width: 767px)  and (min-width: 767px)
media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-widt: 940px)

Comment: Yes, but don't add - modify first media query

Comment: yeah I know I know , I accedently send it before I finished the text.